# Настройка модема STARNET AR800 для раздачи по сети

Tags: сеть, настройка

Имеется модем STARNET AR800 (модем для ADSL), который используется в качестве хаба и wi-fi точки. Интернет приходит по локалке и подключается к первому порту (имеет статистический адрес вида 10.1.2.3), к второму и третему порту подключаются компы. Возможно ли как нибудь задать айпи для первого порта, чтобы второй и третий через него ходили в интернет?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что компы у Вас имеют так же адреса вида 10.1.2.х. Поэтому ответ один - нет.Данный маршрутизатор предназначен для работы ADSL-to-LAN, и как у большинства маршрутизаторов внутренние порты "безмозглые" - т.е. не предусматривают дополнительных настроек.